# Mailchimp API v3 authorisation

Tags: curl, mailchimp

My main goal is to add a user to the list. I'm playing around with curl in the term at the moment to get a handle on the concept of using MailChimp API.

I've done request to add a user to the list:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"apikey" :  "60dd1f3aaa977bf1zzza159yyye93exx-us11","email_address": "urist.mcvankab@freddiesjokes.com","status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"Urist","LNAME":"McVankab"}}' https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/ant6308990/members/
```

This request returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 210
Link:<https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/ProblemDetailDocument.json>; rel="describedBy"
Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 17:22:05 GMT
Connection: close

{"type":"http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/error-docs/401-api-key-missing","title":"API Key Missing","status":401,"detail":"Your request did not include an API key.","instance":"17eb4090-13e4-47ff-aee1-ca62281fe547"}
```

I'm wondering about how to get authorised. Tried to read API docs - came up short. Does anyone know how to devise authorisation request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cURL's `--user` parameter, as shown on MailChimp's [API v3 documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#Authentication_methods).

Answer (score 3):

This is the basic code for PHP/cURL auth in v3 with api key

```
$username = "tcgumus";
   //it can be anything    
$password = "API KEY";    
   // create curl resource     
$ch = curl_init();      
    // set url      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/"); 
    //make sure your dc is correct     
    //return the transfer as a string      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");    
    // $output contains the output string     
$output = curl_exec($ch);     
    // close curl resource to free up system resources     
curl_close($ch);       
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps here:

1. Create your base64 encoded api key: base64_encode(your api user name:api key)
2. Use basic authentication in your CURL request as

   ```
   curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:Basic your base64 encoded string" https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/
   ```
3. Note that you have to use the word "Basic"
4. So in your all curl request add authentication header to authorize your self before making any other request . So in your case try the following

   ```
   curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -H "Content-Type: application/json"
   -H "Authorization:Basic your base64 encoded string"
   -d '{"apikey" :  "60dd1f3aaa977bf1zzza159yyye93exx-us11","email_address": "urist.mcvankab@freddiesjokes.com","status":"subscribed",
   "merge_fields":{"FNAME":"Urist","LNAME":"McVankab"}}' https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/ant6308990/members
   ```

Comment: Did not get what 193105 is. Plus you forget '\', since you used linebreaks inside curl command.

Comment: Yes you are right. it is my mistake, Please remove 193105.